# Why dropping or selecting columns is not working properly with Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following code and result. Here, I am using Databricks' autoloader.

[image]

The result I am getting is not correct, because if I don't drop the columns (df2), I have the following result.

[image]

Note that I notice similar behavior with `select`. What mistake am I doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. I need to explicitly specify that the first line is a header. So, I changed the releavent line to this,

```
df = (spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
      .option("header", "true").schema(schema).load("/FileStore/tables/movies7"))
```